# What is the difference between $a==2 and 2==$a?

Tags: php

In PHP,

If I want to write comparison of variable $a with value 2? Then which way is feasible and when I used first and second solution?

Solutions:

1. $a==2
2. 2==$a

This question was asked by someone in my interview.

Comment: potaytoe, potahtoe. Surely Stack wasn't your first stop. This question's been asked already and often.

Comment: I didn't understand your comment. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Can you give me link of already asked question?

Answer (score 2):

There is a huge difference, in the first example `2` is on `RHS`, and in the second example `2` is on `LHS`. Wait that doesn't matter does it? Nope it makes no difference :)

Some people will say use `2==$a`, in case you mess up and forget one `=` PHP will complain, but that doesn't matter much either. A mess up is a mess up and needs to be resolved regardless. And if that was so important everybody would be using that style but its only a matter of personal preference.

Comment: *"Wait that doesn't matter does it? Nope it makes no difference :) "* - Just like I told 'em: *"potaytoe, potahtoe"* ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The two forms are identical. The reason for using `2==$a` is more to do with what happens if you inadvertently enter `2=$a`.

If you use `$a == 2` you have a comparison, but `$a = 2` is an assignment that will always return a truthy value.

However, if you make the same error with `2==$a` you get `2=$a` and you can't assign a value to a literal. PHP will complain and a bug will have been trapped.

Usage is a matter of style. Some places insist, many don't care.

Answer (score 1):

It is functionally equivalent. However, some people like to write `2 == $a` because `$a == 2` can be made into a serious (and common) bug if you drop an equals sign: `$a = 2` means something very different. Do that with `2 == $a`, and you get a syntax error (`2 = $a` being nonsense), a clear signal that you messed up.

Answer (score -2):

The difference between the two expression is that 
1. `$a==2` checks whether variable 'a' is equal to numeric integer 2 i.e. RHS and 
2. `2==$a` checks whether integer 2 is equal to variable 'a' i.e. LHS