# 'string' == $var or $var == 'string' difference?

Tags: php, syntax

I was reading a piece of code and saw that the author of the code uses the following if statement

```php
if ( 'string' == $var )
```

where as I always use

```php
if ( $var == 'string' )
```

What i'm wondering is if this has any other function except for style/looks. Is comparing a $var to a 'string' quicker/slower than a 'string' to a $var?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29910258/what-is-the-difference-between-a-2-and-2-a/

Comment: It's called yoda condition!

Comment: $var  ='string' ;

if ( 'string' == $var ){
 echo "HI";
} No differenece echoes HI

Comment: The difference is if you make a typo and use `=` instead of `==`

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28840422/3933332

Comment: no difference since $var will be executed by the compiler as 'string' itself.
Its just better practice and formatting of code rather than the issue of right and wrong.

Comment: Maybe the author was a Java developer. Because String comparision isn't the same, you don't use == but a method, equals().
So if you call `var.equals("String")` and var is `null`, you'll get an exception.
The solution is to write `"String".equals(var)`.

Comment: I know for a fact the author is an PHP developer but your comment makes total sense =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Why if( constant == variable ) is preferred instead of if ( variable == constant )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8591182/why-if-constant-variable-is-preferred-instead-of-if-variable-constant)

Here is an answer to your question.
This helps in debugging if you miss an equal sign.

> Because that form makes it harder to introduce a bug by forgetting one
>   of the equals signs. Imagine if you did this:
>
> if (k = 5) This was intended as a comparison, but it's now an
>   assignment! What's worse, it is legal, and it will mess up your
>   program in multiple ways (the value of k is changed, and the
>   conditional always evaluates to true).
>
> Contrast this with
>
> if (5 = k) This is not legal (you cannot assign to a literal) so the
>   compiler will immediately flag it as an error.

in the words of Hanky 웃 Panky in comments:

> They are both equivalent but 'string'==$var is a better approach
>   because it helps in debugging if you miss an equal sign.

Comment: This is a comment not an answer!

Comment: It would have been a very nice answer had you improved your statement to make it complete. Something like `They are both equivalent but 'string'==$var  is a better approach because it helps in debugging if you miss an equal sign.`

Comment: Even though it's not an answer to my question it is in fact what I secretly was looking for without realizing it myself. 

I've always been using the k = 5 notation but do realize now that apparently it's bad practice or well the latter is preferred. I'll see if I can get myself to switching over to 5 = k :)